# htaccess jump to cached file (htaccess & php-Cache)

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching

I have webpages processed by php. When they're finished processing and i get a html-file output. This file is saved in a directory called "cache".

e.g.

```
www.domain.tld/list.html (browser-url)
www.domain.tld/cache/list.html (cached-file)
```

My actual problem is, that i have no clue how I could change the htaccess-file to work out the problem.

How can I apply that the RewriteCond will check first if the "/list.html"-file exists in that folder (cache) and then (if yes): return the file and (if not) just continue to the other conditions which will in the end redirect to index.php.

But i need to keep the rule, that it have to check if the file exists anyway (without that cache-folder)

This is causing errors:

```
RewriteCond cache/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

How is that possible?

Some of the pages are processed for about 20-30 seconds or more. This is why I want to save them after processing and then deliver the already finished site to save time.

Comment: `REQUEST_FILENAME` can contain the _full_ local path, if that has been determined at this time already - so prefixing that with `cache/` would not lead to any location that would make sense in that case. Try working with `REQUEST_URI` here instead, that is the URL path as it was requested, so that would be `/list.html` in this case.

Comment: Or do it this way, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899206/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-cache-using-htaccess-load-normal-script-if-no

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you ask:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /cache/%1 [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you a lot for that quick response. I will try that today. BTW: You mentioned you'd rather not use htaccess (dynamic conf files). What do you prefer instead? httpd.conf?

Comment: The http server's configuration files are those central files configuring the whole server, not just a part of a specific location inside the file system. They are typically installed into the system along the server itself, though you certainly can modify them and add files to that section. Typically they are located under `/etc/apache2/...` or `/etc/httpd/...`, but that may vary. And yes, a "httpd.conf" file might be among those files, though naming and layout of that folders content vary on the package you installed and the system distribution you use.

Comment: I checked my phpinfo-Output: _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] gives me "/home/trax/public_html". After `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /cache/%1 [END]` didnt work, i changed [END] to [L,QSA]. This didnt work neither. So i tried to to replaced `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%1 -f` with `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/trax_application/webpage/_trax/cache/%1 -f` to my file. This did not work neither with [END] nor [L,QSA]. Then i changed `RewriteRule ^ /cache/%1 [END]` to `RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/trax_application/webpage/_trax/cache_html/%1 [END]`.

Comment: So, is `/home/trax/public_html/cache/...` the correct absolute path to the files in the cache or not? This is not clear from neither your question nor your comment... If the path is correct and the posted rule set does not work then something else is off. Please check your http server's error file... any hint there? What happens if you place a definite syntax error in your configuration, does _that_ lead to an entry in the error log file?